# sending requests from many IP's

Tags: proxy, load-balancing

Is there a service I can use to balance requests between many IP addresses? I need to run some tests and want to send out http requests from a pool of say 100 IP addresses. I don't want to incur the financial and time costs of spinning up 100 VM's and balancing the requests between them. I was hoping there is a service I can use that will do this for me.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you just do all the requests from a single IP? There are enough port numbers, that you could easily have 100 TCP connections open from different client port numbers.

Comment: https://www.blitz.io/ is one such service.

Comment: @kasperd the requests need to be routed via different IP addresses, not ports.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks, see my comment below in reply to ticoombs

Comment: @JamieD Are you trying to get around someone's rate limiting?

Comment: @ceejayoz yes that's correct. The provider has designed their api to work with lots of apps, e.g. mobile apps. So requests will all come from different IP addresses. As mine is a web app all requests come from the same IP. I'm not able to utilise the clients by using JS as the requests need to be queued to run in the background

Comment: Rather than circumventing protections that many of us are in charge of putting in place and managing, why not work with the provider for a whitelisting?

Comment: @ceejayoz I've tried, they responded that their limit is fine for most use cases even though I've explained my use case and given examples. Their site states they offer paid access without limits but when enquiring about this service they simply reply with "the api limit is high enough for most use cases". It's taken weeks to get each response , if they aren't willing to work with me I'm forced to find another way to use their API, hence this post. As you can see I'm willing to pay for a service or even spin up many VM's at expense so I'm not trying to get something for free here.

Comment: Well, that's their right. This site generally doesn't look kindly on "help me circumvent security/abuse/TOS restrictions" questions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about circumventing a site's TOS/abuse limitations.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Tor.  It will use a random paths to your server each time and so will appear from different addresses.

Comment: That's an interesting option, I'm going to keep it as a backup option for now simply because the ruby Tor library is very old (https://github.com/bendiken/tor-ruby) and would require some updating or rewriting to get it working with current versions of ruby and tor.

Answer (score 0):

If you are serious about it, then I would use [Load Impact](http://loadimpact.com)
They have a free tier for 200 concurrent users for 5 minutes.

I believe you even get to script the testing functionality as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure a load testing service would work for this specific case. I need to send specific requests every time (and receive the response back) from my Ruby application. I need these requests to be routed via many different IP addresses.